# How check bitcoin balance with QBitNinja client without own node?

Tags: c#, .net, blockchain, bitcoin, nbitcoin

Can i check bitcoin balance by address with QBitNinja client without my own node?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new QBitNinjaClient(Network.TestNet);
        var address = new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("1May3uZes7Qh629mPG8WXZbMjhZQJ6QeRK");
        var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by using [QbitNinja public nodes](https://qbitninja.docs.apiary.io/#reference/blocks)

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new QBitNinjaClient("http://api.qbit.ninja/", Network.TestNet);
        var address = new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("1May3uZes7Qh629mPG8WXZbMjhZQJ6QeRK");
        var balance = await client.GetBalance(address);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

No. The [readme](https://github.com/MetacoSA/QBitNinja) specifies BitCoin Core, synchronized (so a full node), as a pre-requisite. The [Setup the indexer](https://github.com/MetacoSA/QBitNinja#setup-the-indexer) section also states that it listens to a full node.

Comment: And there are not exists any public nodes to which i can connect? Is it necessary to run own node?